# Why my R studio insert chunk short cut not working

Tags: insert, rstudio, shortcut, chunks

In starting the R studio insert chunk default shortcut (ctrl+alt+i) was working properly. After some time, while i am going to use it the same shortcut just prints **i** in a other manner. I don't understand this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbvhc.png)

I had tried many possible solutions that include changing the short cut, rewriting the short cut. None of them work properly.

Comment: Did you recently update RStudio? What version are you using? I recently updated to 2023.12.0 Build 369 and it affected the alt drag cursor option for multiline editing. Could be a bug.

Comment: Try restarting RStudio and/or your machine.